# How to display only parts of several urls into one html file?

Tags: html, frameset-iframe

In the past I was using iframe but it displayed all the webpage urls contents in full.

For example: I have saved the following code in a file named "trial.html" :

```
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered" width=1100 height=1500></iframe>
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/questions" width=1100 height=1500></iframe>
```

**When I load my file "trial.html" in firefox it shows the two urls properly. ;)**

---

But, for instance, I would like that my webpage **show me only the top right "vote" part (gray color) for the first url**. I notice that it has the following code :

```
<div class="module">
        <div class="summarycount" style="text-align: left;">11,308</div>
        <p>questions with <b style="color: maroon;">no upvoted answers</b></p>

        <p>The highest voted unanswered questions appear first, then the most recent ones. </p>        
    </div>
```

---

**Is it possible to display only the part *`<div class="summarycount"`* or the  *`<div class="module">`* part?**

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: The beauty of iframe in my case is: I have dragged the "trial.html" as a bookmark in firefox. So I just have to click once on my bookmark and load the html file and read only the content that I want to read. But my display is not visually perfect (even with width & height numbers adjusted)!

Comment: It is because the content part is changing: more or less text is displayed inside each of the webpages.

Answer (score 3):

Frames are just another viewport, same as your basic browser window, and all a viewport does is provide a place to display documents. Whole documents.

If you want to parse a document, or indeed many documents, to pick and choose sections of them and merge into another document, you'll have to engage a server-side language to load those documents up and do the surgery for you. As always, I recommend XSLT for this where the documents are well formed, but every language is capable of doing this.

If you really *really* wanted a guerilla option, IF you have control over the documents AND you don't have x-domain worries, you could do some JS DOM manipulation to read from iframe loaded documents and copy the important nodes into the parent document, deleting the iframe as you go, but it's nothing like as clean or reliable.

Comment: Thanks. But I prefer to avoid any server programming. ;)

Comment: Then unfortunately your answer - for anything but very specific cases where you can use JS - is that you can't do this.

Comment: Thank you. ;) FWIW, I think I may have found another solution (see below).

Answer (score 0):

I think this can also do the trick (but it won't do it imho for robot-no-follow html file websites):

Build a Web Page Monitor with Google Docs and Track Changes Automatically
http://www.labnol.org/internet/monitor-web-pages-changes-with-google-docs/4536/